# What is the mechanism for nitration of cinnamaldehyde?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

The group added on to the benzene ring(-CH=CH-CH=O) should be an electron withdrawing group, yet the sources I found online suggest an ortho-/para- product rather than the expected meta product. Is there an explanation for this and preferably a mechanism for the reaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I regret that the OP did not provide a link to the o,p-nitration of cinnamaldehyde. HotLasagna's surmise that m-nitration should apply is well-founded. I did a reaction search on Chem. Absts. for the nitration of cinnamaldehyde without success. Because cinnamaldehyde is a vinolog of benzaldehyde, the latter should serve as a model for the former. The literature confirms the preferred m-nitration of benzaldehyde.
Continuous flow nitration<sup>[[1]](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/op900129w)</sup> ($\ce{HNO3/H2SO4}$) of benzaldehyde gives high yields of the o:m-isomers (1:4) without mention of p-nitrobenzaldehyde. Two additional methods employ trifluoromethanesulfonic anhydride (triflic anhydride) in conjunction with tetramethyl ammonium nitrate or ethyl ammonium nitrate. In the former case<sup>[[2]](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jo026202q)</sup>, the o:m:p ratio was 31/63/6 while in the latter study<sup>[[3]](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jo201374a)</sup> the o:m:p ratio was 27:70:3.
Contrary to the rational suggested by @ M. L., the determining factor is (would be) the destabilization of the positive charge by the aldehyde and vinylogous aldehyde groups in **1** and **3**, respectively, whereas the m-nitration resonance structures **2** and **4** avoid this problem. (Not all of the canonical resonance structures are shown.)

[image]

1. A. A. Kulkarni, V. S. Kalyani, R. A. Joshi and R. R. Joshi, [*Org. Proc. Res. & Dev.*, **2009**, *13*, 999](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/op900129w).
2. S. A. Shackelford, et al., [*J. Org. Chem*. **2003**, *68*, 267](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jo026202q).
3. G. Aridoss and K. K. Laali, [*J. Org. Chem.* **2011**, *76*, 8088](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jo201374a).

Comment: Nitration of Cinnamaldehyde with acetyl nitrate giving o product  http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV4P0722  The references to the Org Syn mention this procedure giving a mixture of o and p  Davey and Gwilt, J. Chem. Soc., 1955, 1384. No mention is made of m product

Comment: @Waylander: Well, so much for Chem Absts. and reasoning by analogy! The Davey/Gwilt paper does not mention which nitrocinnamaldehyde is formed---at least to my reading of it. The yield is of o-nitrocinnamaldehyde is modest after recrystallization. I wonder what other isomers might be in the mother liquors. What do you think about an internal delivery of -NO2 by some derivative of the -CHO and intermediate isomerization of the double bond to cis? A 7-membered TS and perhaps too far fetched.

Comment: An LCMS of the reaction mixture would certainly be interesting. I suspect that different regioisomer mixtures are obtained from different conditions. The acetyl nitrate conditions could possibly give rise to the intermediate you suggest.

Comment: @user55119: I agree with you. I think they were looking for only o-nitro product and got that. Other 50+% should be down the drain! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Deciding how a group will affect an aromatic ring in electrophilic substitution comes from analyzing the possible resonance structures. With cinnamaldehyde, we can draw the possible forms of the para (which should be the same as ortho) and meta addition:

[image]

Clearly, the para/ortho configuration allows for an additional resonance form to take place utilizing the group added to the benzene ring. This higher stability of the resonance with para/ortho addition is likely why electrophilic addition to cinnamaldehyde favours those two configurations.